How to find all possible new positions with a given distance to one or more given 3D coordinates?
Suppose we have a set of 3D coordinates (x, y, z) in a cubic box, just like a molecule or a unit of crystal lattice in chemistry. Now I want to place a new “atom” inside the box, and I want it to be like:

Given a fixed distance D
At least one known atom is found around the new atom with the distance exactly to be D
No known atoms are allowed to be within the D
If there are more than one known atoms are at the distance of D to the new atoms, record the counts of them.

I have worked out a solution for myself but not sure if there’s any better way to solve it.
My solution is briefly as follows (my coded version is here:actual_code):

Build a kd-tree for all the known coordinates.
From all the known coordinates, construct a “sphere” with center at the coordinates and the radius to be my desired D
Now iterates the tree, for every node, find nodes within the radius of 2D, and then do the maths to determine if they intersect at a point, or a circle (not a filled circle but the outline of it, as I want exactly at D)
Save the results for points and circles. Build an array for the circles, iterate it in a O(n^2) way to check if every circles intersects with the other circles. I use a simple track table to avoid checking two identical circles together, and a counter to count the number of times the circle intersects with the other. If the counter is zero, the this circle is pure, representing positions that connects only two known coordinates at the distance of D. If the circles intersects, then the allowed positions to fulfill the D to all atoms related to the circles collapsed into points.
Because the computer has inevitable fluctuations in float point number calculations, I set an epsilon of 1e-6 to “merge” all the points obtained from the previous calculations.
For the “pure circles” I further examined if there are atoms closer than D to the circles, other than the related two atoms generating this circle. I use the kd-tree again to do this. I use the circle radius + D as the maximum tolerance to find_within_radius. For the found atoms, check to see if there is any point on the circle can have a distance larger than the D so we have at least one position from the circle that is free from other atoms.

There are a few more brute-force efforts to make sure the results do not miss any atoms closer than D. So far I have tested my program with several chemical compound and lattice slab models and the results are exactly my expectations. However, for some specific cases with just around 100 atoms but with high symmetry, the program hangs for seconds to output the results. Since I learnt coding by myself without a solid background of maths and computer science, I wonder if there is any better strategy and algorithm from the beginning.

I have mentioned I add the tolerance of 1e-6 to solve the floating point accuracy problem. Thank you for the comment.

Typically there are 70-200 known points in the model. The Delaunay triangulation seems not a very direct solution to my problem, that I have to find positions based on a given distance. Thank you any way

Why the distance doesn’t matter? My problem comes from a real need in our computational chemistry research. We want to find all the possible positions to let a new atom to form bonds with a target bond length to the existing atoms.

I think I have explained clearly enough in the first part of my post. Because it is finding all possible positions so it could form a continuous sphere surface, a circle and even an arc, on which the nearest known points are at the given distance away.

OK, surely "sphere" covers all three of those cases?  That is what is confusing me, sorry

I have clearly stated that besides spheres, there are also possible circles and circle-circle intersections. I don’t think you have the patience to understand my question, it’s becoming a waste of time to discuss with you anymore.

Could it be that you're looking for
Sphere-sphere intersections.
There are many great tutorials:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/75775/86883
(Here's the famous book on the matter!)

